# Can I get a battery percentage for a non-Apple BT device from the command line in Catalina?

Tags: command-line, battery, bluetooth, headphones

I used `ioreg` and the only one of my connected devices that seems to report its battery level is the Trackpad:

```
╰─➤  ioreg -l | grep -B 20 BatteryPercent\"
    | | | | |   |     |   "MaxInputReportSize" = 5
    | | | | |   |     | }
    | | | | |   |     |
    | | | | |   |     +-o AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService  <class AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService, id 0x100001e17, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 7>
    | | | | |   |         {
    | | | | |   |           "LowBatteryNotificationPercentage" = 2
    | | | | |   |           "PrimaryUsagePage" = 65280
    | | | | |   |           "BatteryFaultNotificationType" = "TPBatteryFault"
    | | | | |   |           "VersionNumber" = 0
    | | | | |   |           "VendorID" = 76
    | | | | |   |           "IOUserClientClass" = "IOHIDEventServiceUserClient"
    | | | | |   |           "Built-In" = No
    | | | | |   |           "DeviceAddress" = "3c-7d-0a-5d-1a-82"
    | | | | |   |           "WakeReason" = "Host (0x01)"
    | | | | |   |           "Product" = "Magic Trackpad 2"
    | | | | |   |           "SerialNumber" = "3c-7d-0a-5d-1a-82"
    | | | | |   |           "Transport" = "Bluetooth"
    | | | | |   |           "BatteryLowNotificationType" = "TPLowBattery"
    | | | | |   |           "ProductID" = 613
    | | | | |   |           "DeviceUsagePairs" = ({"DeviceUsagePage"=65280,"DeviceUsage"=11},{"DeviceUsagePage"=65280,"DeviceUsage"=20})
    | | | | |   |           "BatteryPercent" = 64
```

This matches what I see in the BT dropdown.

I'd like to get the battery level of my non-Apple BT headphones. Is this possible from the command line?

I see this answer [Check the battery level of connected bluetooth headphones from the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215256/check-the-battery-level-of-connected-bluetooth-headphones-from-the-command-line) but it seems to only work for Apple devices. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215194/how-to-check-the-battery-level-of-devices-connected-via-bluetooth-in-os-x) is 4 years old.

I reached out to the support for this device and they suggested a 3rd party app called Batteries. It has a free trial. It doesn't report any battery level, just that a battery-powered device is connected.

It looks like this is the fault of the manufacturer -- is there some profile they have to support or something? My MX Keys for Mac are the same way.

Comment: That’s not that old a question. Unless you have substantially different question we will refresh the existing question in almost all cases

Comment: The answer on that question is "you can't" -- is that still true nearly 5 years later? SE doesn't have a good way to handle answers that may have become outdated.

Comment: Changed the title to be for the current OS.

Comment: We do have several ways to handle outdated questions. And yes the answer is still no (I updated the answer on the linked post). I have MX keys and no dice on Monterey and lower